Could istiod push new generated route config to proxy automaticly?
When i apply a virtualservie config, which can generate Cluster and RouteConfig of envoy, yaml file is:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloworld-d
  labels:
    app: helloworld-d
    version: v4
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    name: http
  selector:
    app: helloworld-d
    version: v4

My question is that above new added routerConfig could automaticly push update to a proxy just like envoy? Or, should I actively send a discoveryRequest to fetch routerConfig for my proxy?
